# I still can't resolve symbol R

Tags: android

my android studio cannot resolve symbol R. everyone keeps saying all you have to do is check your XML files and sync bla bla. i have done all that like 10 times now but still. there is no error in my XML files. please someone should tell me something different

Comment: try to clean your project.

Comment: Nah it wont work without recreating indexes. Android studio can be stubborn and stupid sometimes

Answer (score 0):

Use invalidate caches and restart option from the first menu (on a phone so can't remember the menu name) . That should work. After all is done, make sure to also clean build to ensure everything is fine.

Comment: thanks, but no luck still. maybe i should change from version 25 to 26.